# Failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED. Brand New Samsung SSD Drive errors

Tags: ssd

I've installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 20.04.2 yesterday on a new 500gb Samsung 860 SSD, all updated. I was checking the syslog, "cat syslog | grep fail"

And I found lots of these

Mar  6 08:12:36 plex kernel: [ 5610.512841] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000009
Mar  6 08:12:36 plex kernel: [ 5610.512878] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Mar  6 08:12:36 plex kernel: [ 5610.512930] ata1.00: cmd 61/00:40:d0:4c:37/01:00:33:00:00/40 tag 8 ncq dma 131072 out
Mar  6 08:12:36 plex kernel: [ 5610.512930]          res 40/00:00:d0:61:37/00:00:33:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
Mar  6 08:12:36 plex kernel: [ 5610.513055] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Mar  6 08:12:36 plex kernel: [ 5610.513089] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Mar  6 08:12:36 plex kernel: [ 5610.513140] ata1.00: cmd 61/00:48:d0:4d:37/0a:00:33:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq dma 1310720 ou
Mar  6 08:12:36 plex kernel: [ 5610.513140]          res 40/00:00:d0:61:37/00:00:33:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
Mar  6 08:12:36 plex kernel: [ 5610.513264] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }

and 3 of these

ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Mar  6 09:47:23 plex kernel: [ 1404.063654] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Mar  6 09:47:23 plex kernel: [ 1404.063861] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED

and these

ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Mar  6 08:27:11 plex kernel: [  281.098527] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Mar  6 08:27:11 plex kernel: [  281.098658] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
sata1.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0xfff00 SErr 0x0 action 0x0loads of these.

I've looked to see if there are any particular drivers for the Disk.

But do I have a duff disk or is the motherboard a little too old (5-is years I think, it's an old ESXi server)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Samsung 860 series drive by any change? See bug https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203475

The issue is caused by Samsung 860 firmware bug that was originally avoided by Linux kernel due poor historical performance of Samsung SSD drives. The Samsung marketing department promised that 860 firmware has fixed the problem but looking around the net with these errors makes it pretty clear that the 860 firmware is still broken.